# Sign in to Google Play Games Services choose account window is transparent

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have implemented signing in to the games services for my Android game app as it is explained in here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin

Everything works fine and there's no functional error. However, there is a displaying error. If I am not signed in and I click the sign in button, there is this 'Connecting to Google Play Games Services window' and then there's a dialog that says 'Choose account for Google Play Games'. And here's the problem: this dialog has a transparent background so I can hardly see the dialog itself. Sometimes it displays the background correctly but most of the times it doesn't!
Is this problem known?

The dialog looks like this: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-0hAt0IftbyE/VkTZCePNuWI/AAAAAAAACVg/RO6kGr_oQoI/s1600/chooseaccount2.png
It just says 'Choose account for Google Play Games' and it has no white background.

I have googled but couldn't find anything about this problem. It can't be that it's just me who has this problem.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Edit: I found out that this is just an issue on my device. If someone of you had this problem as well and could figure out how to solve it, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried checking this on other android test devices to see if this is a device or a code issue?

Comment: Good point! No, I haven't because I don't have another device but I will try with a friend's device and figure it out

Comment: What happened when you used your friend's device? Was the display normal?

Comment: Actually yes, the display was normal. I don't understand why it is different on my phone. What I also found out on my device is when the game is running for a few minutes already and I then want to sign in, it shows the dialog correctly as well. It is just when I press sign in as soon as the app started.

Comment: Since we've confirmed this is not a code issue, you can close this thread by marking it as Answered by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Hi, a bit off topic, but I'm trying to implement an account picker that looks just like yours. What method/class did you use for it. I've raised an SO question to show you what I mean. I'm aiming for it to look like yours, but can't seem to replicate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799247/android-struggling-to-style-account-picker

Answer (score 0):

As have been discussed
in the comments,
this is a device issue- a case of Android fragmentation.