# Android - struggling to style Account Picker

Tags: android, accountmanager, accountpicker

I'm trying to implement an AccountPicker in my game, and I've tried using all three versions of `newChooseAccountIntent`, 2 coming from `AccountManager` and one from `AccountPicker`.

my code looks like this

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE}, null, null, null, null);
} else {
    intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE}, false, null, null, null, null);
}
```

or the same, but replace `AccountManager` for `AccountPicker`

My aim is to have a picker that looks like this

[image: ideal picker]

But using `AccountManager` I get

[image: AccountManager]

which is at least Material in colour

or this from `AccountPicker` (ICS!!)

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I thought it might be that the `AccountManager` is populating the first field which is selectedAccount, but when I did that, it just selected the radio button against the appropriate account.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I am in the same situation

Comment: No :-( If you work it out, let me know!! And post it and I'll accept your answer

Comment: I hope one day... :P. But it's obviously a missing feature

Answer (score -2):

You can use Google Api Client [document](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.